# NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{...}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I know that question has already been treated but with all my attemps, no way to fix my issue.

I just installed elasticsearch and boot it. Here the log of elastic :

```
[2017-05-17T00:05:27,290][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [] initializing ...
[2017-05-17T00:05:27,394][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [xhkU1rX] using [1] data paths, mounts [[Data (D:)]], net usable_space [25gb], net total_space [138.4gb], spins? [unknown], types [NTFS]
[2017-05-17T00:05:27,395][INFO ][o.e.e.NodeEnvironment    ] [xhkU1rX] heap size [1.9gb], compressed ordinary object pointers [true]
[2017-05-17T00:05:28,331][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] node name [xhkU1rX] derived from node ID [xhkU1rXqQ1OgNhIOdfkifg]; set [node.name] to override
[2017-05-17T00:05:28,332][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] version[5.4.0], pid[7944], build[780f8c4/2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z], OS[Windows 7/6.1/amd64], JVM[Oracle Corporation/Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM/1.8.0_101/25.101-b13]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,421][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [aggs-matrix-stats]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,422][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [ingest-common]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,422][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [lang-expression]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,422][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [lang-groovy]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,422][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [lang-mustache]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,422][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [lang-painless]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,423][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [percolator]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,423][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [reindex]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,423][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [transport-netty3]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,423][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded module [transport-netty4]
[2017-05-17T00:05:30,424][INFO ][o.e.p.PluginsService     ] [xhkU1rX] loaded plugin [x-pack]
[2017-05-17T00:05:34,242][DEBUG][o.e.a.ActionModule       ] Using REST wrapper from plugin org.elasticsearch.xpack.XPackPlugin
[2017-05-17T00:05:34,804][INFO ][o.e.x.m.j.p.l.CppLogMessageHandler] [controller/11204] [Main.cc@128] controller (64 bit): Version 5.4.0 (Build 120b96fa7f6fa7) Copyright (c) 2017 Elasticsearch BV
[2017-05-17T00:05:34,863][INFO ][o.e.d.DiscoveryModule    ] [xhkU1rX] using discovery type [zen]
[2017-05-17T00:05:36,769][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] initialized
[2017-05-17T00:05:36,772][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xhkU1rX] starting ...
[2017-05-17T00:05:38,384][INFO ][o.e.t.TransportService   ] [xhkU1rX] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9300}, {[::1]:9300}
[2017-05-17T00:05:41,441][INFO ][o.e.c.s.ClusterService   ] [xhkU1rX] new_master {xhkU1rX}{xhkU1rXqQ1OgNhIOdfkifg}{Ki_4aUviS3m6n36CQ73tVw}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}{ml.enabled=true}, reason: zen-disco-elected-as-master ([0] nodes joined)
[2017-05-17T00:05:43,372][INFO ][o.e.l.LicenseService     ] [xhkU1rX] license [78f22813-a953-4397-ab90-d9e057e7647e] mode [trial] - valid
[2017-05-17T00:05:43,399][INFO ][o.e.g.GatewayService     ] [xhkU1rX] recovered [28] indices into cluster_state
[2017-05-17T00:05:45,462][INFO ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4HttpServerTransport] [xhkU1rX] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {127.0.0.1:9200}, {[::1]:9200}
[2017-05-17T00:05:45,474][INFO ][o.e.n.Node               ] [xhkU1rX] started
[2017-05-17T00:05:47,834][INFO ][o.e.c.r.a.AllocationService] [xhkU1rX] Cluster health status changed from [RED] to [YELLOW] (reason: [shards started [[my-index][3]] ...]).
```

So, Elastic is fully running and listenning on the port 9300.

My cluster name is "my-application".

Confirmed by elasticsearch.yml :

```
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
cluster.name: my-application
#
```

And also confirmed by requesting http://localhost:9200/ :

```
{
  "name" : "xhkU1rX",
  "cluster_name" : "my-application",
  "cluster_uuid" : "ygmbc6k0TpKdJP77OJeG9g",
  "version" : {
    "number" : "5.4.0",
    "build_hash" : "780f8c4",
    "build_date" : "2017-04-28T17:43:27.229Z",
    "build_snapshot" : false,
    "lucene_version" : "6.5.0"
  },
  "tagline" : "You Know, for Search"
}
```

Here is my Maven dependencies (versions of elastic and client are aligned) :

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-to-slf4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.7</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.21</version>
</dependency>
```

And here my java piece of code :

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException {
        Settings clusterSettings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "my-application")
                .build();

        TransportClient transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(clusterSettings)
                .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));

        try {
            SearchResponse response = transportClient
                    .prepareSearch()
                    .execute().actionGet();
            System.out.println(response.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            transportClient.close();
        }
    }
}
```

that gives me the following logs :

```
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{nqelLN69RhSJabcb57_lWQ}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:348)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:366)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
    at Test.main(Test.java:23)
```

If I try to execute this command on a terminal :

```
telnet 127.0.0.1 9300
```

I'm prompted and I can enter only 6 (invisible) characters and elastic console display (I typed azerty) :

```
[2017-05-17T00:30:33,573][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4Transport] [xhkU1rX] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xda47cab8, L:/127.0.0.1:9300 - R:/127.0.0.1:64226]], closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (61,7a,65,72)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:248) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:86) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:340) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1334) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:362) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:348) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:926) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:134) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:624) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysPlain(NioEventLoop.java:524) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:478) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:438) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (61,7a,65,72)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.validateMessageHeader(TcpTransport.java:1257) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[?:?]
        ... 19 more
[2017-05-17T00:30:33,577][WARN ][o.e.x.s.t.n.SecurityNetty4Transport] [xhkU1rX] exception caught on transport layer [[id: 0xda47cab8, L:/127.0.0.1:9300 ! R:/127.0.0.1:64226]], closing connection
io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (61,7a,65,72)
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:442) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:375) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInputClosed(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:342) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelInactive(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:325) ~[netty-codec-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelInactive(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:75) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:224) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1329) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:245) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelInactive(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:231) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelInactive(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:908) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$7.run(AbstractChannel.java:744) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163) [netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:403) [netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:442) [netty-transport-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858) [netty-common-4.1.9.Final.jar:4.1.9.Final]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid internal transport message format, got (61,7a,65,72)
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.TcpTransport.validateMessageHeader(TcpTransport.java:1257) ~[elasticsearch-5.4.0.jar:5.4.0]
        at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty4.Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.decode(Netty4SizeHeaderFrameDecoder.java:36) ~[?:?]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) ~[?:?]
        ... 20 more
```

It means that the port 9300 is the good one.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

Someowe can help me ?

**EDIT**
Here is the complete logs after configuring log4j with TRACE on org.elasticsearch :

```
0    [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - plugin loaded from classpath [- Plugin information:
Name: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin
Description: classpath plugin
Version: NA
Native Controller: false
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin]
21   [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - plugin loaded from classpath [- Plugin information:
Name: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin
Description: classpath plugin
Version: NA
Native Controller: false
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
24   [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - plugin loaded from classpath [- Plugin information:
Name: org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin
Description: classpath plugin
Version: NA
Native Controller: false
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
25   [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - plugin loaded from classpath [- Plugin information:
Name: org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin
Description: classpath plugin
Version: NA
Native Controller: false
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
28   [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - plugin loaded from classpath [- Plugin information:
Name: org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MustachePlugin
Description: classpath plugin
Version: NA
Native Controller: false
 * Classname: org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MustachePlugin]
41   [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - no modules loaded
43   [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.index.reindex.ReindexPlugin]
43   [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.percolator.PercolatorPlugin]
43   [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.script.mustache.MustachePlugin]
43   [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty3Plugin]
43   [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.plugins.PluginsService  - loaded plugin [org.elasticsearch.transport.Netty4Plugin]
112  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [force_merge], size [1], queue size [unbounded]
116  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [fetch_shard_started], core [1], max [8], keep alive [5m]
116  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [listener], size [2], queue size [unbounded]
121  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [index], size [4], queue size [200]
122  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [refresh], core [1], max [2], keep alive [5m]
122  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [generic], core [4], max [128], keep alive [30s]
122  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [warmer], core [1], max [2], keep alive [5m]
123  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [search], size [7], queue size [1k]
123  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [flush], core [1], max [2], keep alive [5m]
123  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [fetch_shard_store], core [1], max [8], keep alive [5m]
124  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [management], core [1], max [5], keep alive [5m]
124  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [get], size [4], queue size [1k]
124  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [bulk], size [4], queue size [200]
124  [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.threadpool.ThreadPool  - created thread pool: name [snapshot], core [1], max [2], keep alive [5m]
1301 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.common.network.IfConfig  - configuration:

lo
        Software Loopback Interface 1
        inet 127.0.0.1 netmask:255.0.0.0 broadcast:127.255.255.255 scope:host
        inet6 ::1 prefixlen:128 scope:host
        UP MULTICAST LOOPBACK mtu:-1 index:1
[...] other wetwork interfaces [...]

2395 [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.HierarchyCircuitBreakerService  - parent circuit breaker with settings [parent,type=PARENT,limit=2622960435/2.4gb,overhead=1.0]
2396 [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.request  - creating ChildCircuitBreaker with settings [request,type=MEMORY,limit=2248251801/2gb,overhead=1.0]
2396 [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.fielddata  - creating ChildCircuitBreaker with settings [fielddata,type=MEMORY,limit=2248251801/2gb,overhead=1.03]
2396 [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.in_flight_requests  - creating ChildCircuitBreaker with settings [in_flight_requests,type=MEMORY,limit=3747086336/3.4gb,overhead=1.0]
2538 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService  - node_sampler_interval[5s]
3373 [main] DEBUG org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService  - adding address [{#transport#-1}{1hiyV12vSMewRrjSv9ZmmA}{192.168.56.1}{192.168.56.1:9300}]
4016 [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.request  - [request] Adjusted breaker by [16440] bytes, now [16440]
4059 [elasticsearch[_client_][transport_client_boss][T#1]] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.request  - [request] Adjusted breaker by [-16440] bytes, now [0]
4059 [elasticsearch[_client_][transport_client_boss][T#1]] TRACE org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.tracer  - [1][internal:tcp/handshake] sent to [{#transport#-1}{1hiyV12vSMewRrjSv9ZmmA}{192.168.56.1}{192.168.56.1:9300}] (timeout: [null])
4085 [main] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.request  - [request] Adjusted breaker by [16440] bytes, now [16440]
4087 [elasticsearch[_client_][transport_client_boss][T#1]] TRACE org.elasticsearch.indices.breaker.request  - [request] Adjusted breaker by [-16440] bytes, now [0]
4217 [main] INFO  org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService  - failed to get node info for {#transport#-1}{1hiyV12vSMewRrjSv9ZmmA}{192.168.56.1}{192.168.56.1:9300}, disconnecting...
RemoteTransportException[[xhkU1rX][192.168.56.1:9300][cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]]; nested: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]];
Caused by: ElasticsearchSecurityException[missing authentication token for action [cluster:monitor/nodes/liveness]]
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.support.Exceptions.authenticationError(Exceptions.java:39)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.missingToken(DefaultAuthenticationFailureHandler.java:74)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$AuditableTransportRequest.anonymousAccessDenied(AuthenticationService.java:506)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.lambda$handleNullToken$14(AuthenticationService.java:331)
    at org.elasticsearch.xpack.security.authc.AuthenticationService$Authenticator.handleNullToken(AuthenticationService.java:336)
    [...] some additionnal stacktrace [...]
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:858)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{1hiyV12vSMewRrjSv9ZmmA}{192.168.56.1}{192.168.56.1:9300}]]
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.ensureNodesAreAvailable(TransportClientNodesService.java:348)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClientNodesService.execute(TransportClientNodesService.java:246)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportProxyClient.execute(TransportProxyClient.java:59)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient.doExecute(TransportClient.java:366)
    at org.elasticsearch.client.support.AbstractClient.execute(AbstractClient.java:408)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:80)
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ActionRequestBuilder.execute(ActionRequestBuilder.java:54)
    at Test.main(Test.java:22)
```

Comment: Can you show all the logs from your Java app ?

Comment: My Java app doesn't provide lot of logs (only "log4j:" prefixied logs), so if you know how I can configure log4j.properties to display more logs, I will be happy to copy/paste them here ;)

Comment: use below dependency also and check :                                            
                                <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
      <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
    </dependency>

Comment: the dependency you provide is the first transitive dependency of   <dependency>
      <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
      <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
      <version>5.4.0</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, by providing you the logs in the EDIT part of my question, I saw a security exception.
So I asked to myself : which part of ES is providing the security aspect.

The answer is : X-Pack plugin.

So to check if it's realy the source of my troubles, I removed it by using this command :
    `elasticsearch-plugin.bat remove x-pack`

And... it's working well now. Youhou !

Here is the result of my piece of Java code :

```
{
    "took" : 21,
    "timed_out" : false,
    "_shards" : {
        "total" : 44,
        "successful" : 44,
        "failed" : 0
    },
    "hits" : {
        "total" : 306673,
        "max_score" : 1.0,
        "hits" : [{
                "_index" : ".kibana",
                "_type" : "config",
                "_id" : "5.0.0",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {
                    "buildNum" : 14438
                }
            },
            {
                "_index" : ".monitoring-alerts-2",
                "_type" : "doc",
                "_id" : "ygmbc6k0TpKdJP77OJeG9g_elasticsearch_cluster_status",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {[...]}
            },
            {
                "_index" : ".monitoring-data-2",
                "_type" : "kibana",
                "_id" : "60fef358-886c-43cb-9ef1-2257ccd2bcbb",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {[...]}
            },
            {[...]},
            {
                "_index" : ".monitoring-es-2-2017.05.11",
                "_type" : "index_stats",
                "_id" : "AVv3uOacGOX_5IPHNH_2",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "_source" : {[...]}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I just have to look for this security token part but it's another topic.

Many thanks to @andrei-stefan for the helping comment ;)

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered same problem and i solved the mentioned issue by adding `transport.host: localhost` property in **elasticsearch.yml** file.

After adding it, it works as expected. I hope it will help other reader of this thread.

Comment: Thanks bro it helped:)

Comment: Can you explain what will change if I add "transport.host: localhost" to the yml file?

Comment: @valijon To be honest, i have no concrete answer but when you use transport client, your client starts to act like one of the node of the cluster. Default settings for "trasnport.host" may be improper to join the cluster. So when we change the mentioned network settings, it can find the node to connect.

Answer (score 2):

Just for reference, I am using *7.2* while I was trying to use

```
org.elasticsearch.client:transport:5.5.1
```

and following code to connect to my local cluster, and same error popped into my face.

```
public static void main(String... args) {
        TransportClient client = getClient();
        SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("cars").execute().actionGet();
        System.out.println(response);
    }

    private static TransportClient getClient() {
        TransportClient client = null;
        try {
            client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(
                    Settings.builder().put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                            .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch").build())
                    .addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("127.0.0.1"), 9300));
            client.listedNodes();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {

        }
        return client;
    }
```

As I checked the ES console, it's already warned me of the version issues

```
exception caught on transport layer [Netty4TcpChannel{localAddress=/127.0.0.1:9300, remoteAddress=/127.0.0.1:62723}], closing connection
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received handshake message from unsupported version: [5.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [6.8.0]
```

So I just use the new version to fix the error.

```
org.elasticsearch.client:transport:7.2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly this issue, and for me it was the version between elasticsearch running on my host and the elasticsearch version in my IntelliJ pom.xml

When I used the same version on both ends it worked. I.e. I downloaded the same version for my host as my client and then it worked.

I modified this working sample to figure it out:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-elasticsearch

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. My problem was that the cluster name in my /etc/elasticsearch.yml file was different from the cluster name I was referencing in my application.

I made the names match and bingo!

Answer (score 1):

if you are running the elastic search via docker image.
then runt the docker image via below command.

```
docker run -p 9400:9200 -p 9401:9300 -e "http.host=0.0.0.0" -e "transport.host=0.0.0.0" -e "xpack.security.enabled=false" docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.2.2
```

-e "transport.host=127.0.0.1" did not work.

Also settings should be as below. donot add the .put("client.transport.sniff", true).

```
Settings esSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
            .build();
```

Answer (score 1):

Here goes a very simple example: https://github.com/EdersonJunior/ElasticSearch_Java

My elasticsearch.yml file is like that:

```
cluster.name: "elasticsearch"
node.name: "myNode"
network.host: 0.0.0.0
http.port: 9200
```

It's very important you setup the 9300 host port at properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Use ElasticSearch 6.3.1 and Springboot2.0.0.RELASE and do the following changes:

1. Use the following code to connect the your local ElasticSearch Server:

Settings settings = Settings.builder().put("cluster.name", "farkalit-cluster").build();
        transportClient = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings).addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));

2. Update the ESeach..\config\elasticsearch.yml 
   cluster.name: farkalit-cluster

It will solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

This error may come because of the version mismatch. Check in elastic search logs, it will specify more details about the minimum version of elasticsearch client to be used. So either upgrade client jar or run below versions of elasticsearch