# Updating cluster name of existing elasticsearch instance

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

i have updated my cluster name. i have made changes in elasticsearch.yml file, updated clusterName: from 'x' to 'y' and restarted the server. I also made changes to 'renaming the data folder fro x to y' and now i can see the data in elastic head plugin.

i made the same changes in my code for 'cluster name' but i am getting an error NoNodeAvaliable.

for reference - [NoNodeAvailableException[None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{...}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44012778/nonodeavailableexceptionnone-of-the-configured-nodes-are-available-transpor)

i have followed everything, restarted my servers. but still noNodeavailable.

any help will be appreciated. 
thanks

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This answer might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35144801/4604579

Comment: @Val thanks for replying. it did help but i am facing another issue, no node available.
i have checked multiple times and the cluster name is the same as on the code and still getting the same, however i can see the updated clustername on elastic head.

Comment: Which version are you running?

Comment: @Val 2.5.2 is the version.

Comment: Please update your question with all the modifications you just did.

Comment: @Val updated the same.

Comment: Are you sure you have no typos anywhere?

Comment: yep , its just i have one server for elastic and another running the code and communicating to the transport layer

Comment: Can you show the logs of the Elasticsearch server when it restarted?

Comment: nothing much in it. i cannot get you a screen grab though

publish address : the IP:9300
recovered 41 indices

Comment: Please share them

Comment: actually i can't its my prod server (which is inhouse) and i cannot move stuff even with a pd

Comment: Does your client server have the correct host/IP address to connect to your Elasticsearch server? Is the client code also hosted on the same server as Elasticsearch? (since I see `127.0.0.1:9300` in your log)

Comment: @Val yep its all correct

Comment: @Val thanks man really appreciate your help. 

i made a couple of more config changes to elasticsearch.yml  - 
transport.host: xxxxxx (IP) and transport.ip:9300

and did a restart and probably went for lunch came and the boom it worked.
Thanks again. !!!

Comment: Awesome, glad you figured it all out.